# Find a one parameter family of solutions of the following first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find a one parameter family of solutions of the following first order ordinary differential equation

$$(3x^2 + 9xy + 5y^2) dx - (6x^2 + 4xy) dy = 0$$

Hello. So I am stuck after I find out that they are not exact. Please help.

Comment: There is no easy way to write this. Write it as dy/dx, divide out an x^2 from top and bottom, let v=y/x, then v' = (y'-v)/x, then integrate, then etc.

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, **welcome to the site !**

The equation is 
$$3 x^2+9 x y(x)+5 y(x)^2-\left(6 x^2+4 x y(x)\right) y'(x)=0$$ Looking at the last term, let $y(x)=u(x)-\frac 32 x$ to get
$$-4 x u(x) u'(x)+5 u(x)^2+\frac{3 x^2}{4}=0$$ that is to say
$$-2x \left(u^2(x)\right)'+5 u^2(x)+\frac{3 x^2}{4}=0$$ So, let $u(x)=\pm \sqrt{v(x)}$ to get
$$-2 x v'(x)+5 v(x)+\frac{3 x^2}{4}=0$$ which looks to be simple.

Comment: +1 well done Claude

Comment: Hello Claude! Thanks for welcoming me ! Quick question, why did you add extra x's that were not suppose to be in the original question? Is that part of answering the question? Sorry just  a little confused. The original equation was (3x2+9xy+5y2)dx−(6x2+4xy)dy=0

Comment: @s.v. I did not add anything ! Instead of writing $y$ I wrote $y(x)$. May be, I am too puristic ! If you prefer, replace $y(x)$ by $y$, $u(x)$ by $u$ and $v(x)$ by $v$.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating factor is
$$\mu=\frac{1}{xP+yQ}\\=
\frac{1}{x\, \left( 5 {{y}^{2}}+9 x y+3 {{x}^{2}}\right) +y\, \left( -4 x y-6 {{x}^{2}}\right) }\\= \frac{1}{x\, {{y}^{2}}+3 {{x}^{2}} y+3 {{x}^{3}}}\\
$$
General solution is
$$5 \log{(x)}-2 \log{\left( {{y}^{2}}+3 x y+3 {{x}^{2}}\right) }=C$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a homogeneous DE so making $y = u x$ we obtain

$$
x u'=\frac{u(u+3)+3}{4u+6}
$$

which is separable giving

$$
\frac{(4u+6)du}{u(u+3)+3} = \frac{dx}{x}
$$

or

$$
\ln(u(u+3)+3)^2 = C_0 + \ln x\Rightarrow (u(u+3)+3)^2=C_1x
$$

and finally

$$
y = \frac x2\left(-3\pm\sqrt{C_2\sqrt x-3}\right)
$$